# where are my offline sharepoint documents located on my machine from Microsoft SharePoint Workspace 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-workspace

I am using SharePoint 2010. I am using also Microsoft SharePoint Workspace 2010 on my machine (Win 7). When I open Microsoft SharePoint Workspace 2010 I see many lists and documents. I click on work Offline. But where are my offline documents are located on my machine when I turn off the internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, your workspaces are stored in the Workspaces folder in your User Profile folder.

In Windows 7, you must open the Desktop folder to see your User Profile folder.

Then you can open the User Profile folder to see the Workspaces folder.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Accessing-workspace-data-from-your-file-system-in-SharePoint-Workspace-2010-1365ebf2-a45e-45cc-bfc4-bdae528b32f4